# make images expand on hover from center and make image still stay in box

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my images act like this: http://www.kas.tw/ (hover over images beneath the image carousel) but my images expand from the side and I can't figure out how to make the image still stay in its box, here is the code.

CSS

```
#image3{
top: 130%;
left: 20%;
display: none;
}
#cover1{
width: 5%;
height: 100%;
left: 47%;
background-color: green;
z-index: 2;
top: 94%;
position: absolute;
}
.zoom {
    padding: 50px;

    transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */

    margin: 0 auto;
}
.zoom:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5); /* (150% zoom - Note: if the zoom is too large, 
it will go outside of the viewport) */
}
```

HTML

```
<DIV class='zoom' id='image1'><IMG width='50%' height='90%' src="slime3.JPG"></DIV>
        <DIV  id='image2'><IMG width='50%' height='90%' src="slime4.JPG"></DIV>
        <DIV  id='image3'><IMG width='50%' height='90%' src="slime5.JPG"></DIV>
        <DIV  id='image4'><IMG width='50%' height='90%' src="slime6.JPG"></DIV>
        <DIV  id='image5'><IMG width='50%' height='90%' src="slime7.JPG"></DIV>
        <DIV  id='image6'><IMG width='50%' height='90%' src="slime8.JPG"></DIV>
        <DIV id='cover1'><DIV>
            <DIV id='cover2'><DIV>
                <DIV id='cover3'><DIV>
                    <DIV id='cover4'><DIV>
                        <DIV id='cover5'><DIV>
```

Comment: show us your code please

Comment: see here:https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_zoom_hover.asp

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on how to ask a good question, as this will help the community understand your issue and provide you with a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, when I posted I didn't have enough time to add the code

Comment: What is the reason behind your right answer? You stated it should make the image stay in the box and the answer you selected doesn't, it expands.

Comment: I'm new and I didn't know you could only select one answer, both were helpful so I marked both.

Comment: You can hit the up arrow button (up vote) if you find that answer useful.

Comment: Thanks, you let me know that only one answer can be selected.

Comment: Np, yes you can upvote and downvote as many answers you want, even the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make images stay in the box **without expanding its container size**.

This can be done purely on CSS by using `max-width`,`max-height` to set a specific box size and to use `overflow: hidden` to hide the excess image when it expands past the width and height.

`transform: scale(2,2)` allows the image to zoom from the center.

Try this:

```css
#holder {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;

}

#holder img {
  width: 100%;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

#holder img:hover {
  transform: scale(2,2);
}
```

```html
<div id="holder">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
<div class="item">
<img>..</img>
</div>
```

and for css

```
 .item:hover img {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```